# Depending on time of day, give class to certain div elements

Tags: javascript

I require to assign certain classes to my divs depending on the time of the day. So that the list can change con-currently with live time.

Here's what I got for generating displayed time and creating the lists:

```
function date_time() {
        date = new Date;
        year = date.getFullYear();
        month = date.getMonth();
        months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'Jully', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
        d = date.getDate();
        day = date.getDay();
        days = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
        h = date.getHours();
        if (h < 10) {
                h = "0" + h;
        }
        m = date.getMinutes();
        if (m < 10) {
                m = "0" + m;
        }
        s = date.getSeconds();
        if (s < 10) {
                s = "0" + s;
        }
        result = '' + days[day] + ' ' + months[month] + ' ' + d + ' ' + year + ' ' + h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
        document.getElementById("displayTime").innerHTML = result;
        setTimeout(function () {
                date_time()
        }, 1000);
        return true;
}

function makeList() {
        let counter = 12;
        let meridiem = "PM"
        for(let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
                // counter + i = 12 % 12;
                let actualTime = (counter + i) % 12;
                if(actualTime <= 0) {
                        actualTime = 12;
                       if (meridiem == "AM"){
                               meridiem = "PM";
                       } else if (meridiem == "PM") {
                               meridiem = "AM"
                       }
                }
                let div = $("<div>").addClass("row")
                let div1 = $("<div>").addClass("hour col-sm-1").text(actualTime + meridiem)
                let textArea = $("<textarea>").attr("id", "hour" + i).addClass("form-control col-sm-10").attr("rows", 3)
                let save = $("<button>").data("hour", i).addClass("saveBtn col-sm-1")
                let icon = $("<i>").addClass("fas fa-save fa-2x")

                save.append(icon)
                div.append(div1)
                div.append(textArea)
                div.append(save)

                $("#listorsomething").append(div)
        }
}
```

This is what I was trying out :

```
function classChanger() {

        for (let i = 0; i > 24; i++) {
                if(i > date_time.getHours) {
                        $("<div>").addClass("future")
                }if(i < date_time.getHours) {
                        $("<div>").addClass("past")
                }if(i = date_time.getHours) {
                        $("<div>").addClass("present")
                }
        }
}
```

The past, present, and future are classes I have in my css file. I thought calling date_time.getHours would help me define that variable outside of the date_time scope.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you are going to compare the current time to another time. Then you'll need another variable to store the value of it and do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        let date = new Date();
        let time = date.getHours();      

function classChanger(relativeTime) {


        if (relativeTime < time) {
            $("div").addClass("past");
        } else if (relativeTime == time) {
            $("div").addClass("present");
        } else {
            $("div").addClass("future");
        }
}
classChanger(5); // 5 for example

});
```

Here I'm comparing only the hours, but you might need to add minutes and format it properly. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! That is actually giving the class to my div elements. Now I just need to get it to read the time accurately so that my hour slots are shaded properly in my daily planner I am creating. I appreciate your feedback, it helps a lot.

Comment: You're very welcome. I'd be more than glad if you could accept the answer if it solved the issue.